# What are the "ouverts convenables" used to prove Brieskorns lemma?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, hyperplane-arrangements

In the proof of Brieskorns lemma, see 3.3 [here](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/brieskorn8.pdf), Brieskorn mentions that we take "ouverts convenables" satisfying some properties, but, as far as I can tell, never specifies what these opens actually are, or why such opens even exist. None of the other sources that I am aware of discuss a prove of this lemma in more detail, so I wonder if anyone here knows what these opens are supposed to be?